# Ignore regex match on comments

Tags: regex

Im building this regex to match any `hi` but ignore the match if at the endline theres a `;base64`

I would like to also ignore the match case the lines begins with a `;` also dont match in the case theres a `;` preceding the match like on the line 3. (trying to not replace things in comments)

```regex
\bhi\b(?!.*(;base64))
```

https://regex101.com/r/OCMxPY/1

```
1 hi
2 foo hi hi foo
3 foo #hi# ;foo hi
4 ;foo hi
5 foo hi ;base64
6 foo @hi@ foo hih
```

In the case don't match line `3,4,5`

Comment: Line three has a `#hi#` before `;` and a `hi` after `;`. Do you need to match the first `hi`?

Comment: That doesn't look like a comment; `;base64=` is how you encode e.g. a PNG image inline in the [`data:` URI scheme.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the regex flavor. You can use this Perl compatible regex:

```
^(?!.*;.*\bhi\b)(?!.*;base64\b).*\bhi\b
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*;.*\bhi\b)` - negative lookahead to exclude `hi` after `;`
- `(?!.*;base64\b)` - negative lookahead to exclude lines with `;base64`

  - note that `foo hi ;comment` is still a match since `hi` is before the comment
- `.*\bhi\b` - pattern `hi` with word boundaries anywhere in the line

Test case:

```
$ printf "hi\nfoo hi hi foo\nfoo #hi# ;foo hi\n;foo hi\nfoo hi ;base64\nfoo @hi@ foo hih\nfoo hi ;comment\n"
hi
foo hi hi foo
foo #hi# ;foo hi
;foo hi
foo hi ;base64
foo @hi@ foo hih
foo hi ;comment
$
$ printf "hi\nfoo hi hi foo\nfoo #hi# ;foo hi\n;foo hi\nfoo hi ;base64\nfoo @hi@ foo hih\nfoo hi ;comment" \
>  | grep -P '^(?!.*;.*\bhi\b)(?!.*;base64\b).*\bhi\b'
hi
foo hi hi foo
foo @hi@ foo hih
foo hi ;comment
$
```

Comment: nice explain about the negative lookahead